# Somar subtotal com jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,

Acessem este site: conepa.agenciaweblab.com.br/inscricoes
Pessoal, estou com um probleminha, no meu sistema de carrinho,
estou conseguindo multiplicar o valor com a quantidade de cada loop, porem nao estou fazendo o loop do carrinho com javascript, estou fazendo com php, e eu preciso somar os valores dos subtotais, gostaria de alguma solução.
Principais campos:

```
<td class="price-col" id="preco_<?= $list_cart->post_id; ?>" data-valor="<?= $list_cart->post_valor; ?>"><?= $list_cart->post_valor; ?></td>
<td class="quantity-col">
   <input type="number" onChange="Multiplica(<?= $list_cart->post_id; ?>)" class="form-control qtd_<?= $list_cart->post_id; ?>" <?= $disabled; ?> min="1" max="<?= $list_cart->post_quantidade; ?>" placeholder="0" required="">
```

e agora o jquery:

```
function Multiplica(id) {

    var valor = $('#preco_' + id).text();
    var quantidade = $('.qtd_' + id).val();
    var total = valor * quantidade;
    document.getElementById('sub_' + id).innerHTML = number_format(total, '2', ',', '.');

    var totals = 0;
    $('#preco_' + id).each(function () {
        totals += (valor * quantidade);
    });
    $("#totalSoma").text(totals);
}
```

alguém para ajudar? só preciso da soma total, o que eu fiz, não teve muito sucesso.

Comment: Onde fica o campo com id `totalSoma`?

Comment: é apenas um span, fora do loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há apenas um equivoco em `$('#preco_' + id).each(function () {});`, pois só é executado para uma unica td que esta na mesma linha do input que foi alterada a quantidade. Imagino que você quisesse que fossem acessadas todas as tags td que possuem id começando com `preco_` e fosse calculada a quantidade total. Para isso basta uma pequena modificação na sua busca. Veja:

```
function Multiplica(id) {

        var valor = $('#preco_' + id).text();
        var quantidade = $('.qtd_' + id).val();
        var total = valor * quantidade;
        document.getElementById('sub_' + id).innerHTML = number_format(total, '2', ',', '.');

        var totals = 0;
        //procura todos os elementos em que o id começa com preco_ e que está dentro de uma td
        $("td[id^='preco_']").each(function () {
            //conteudo da tag td que tem id começando com #preco_
            var valor = $(this).text();
            //encontra a tag tr pai da tag td, depois encontra a tag quantity-col 
            //e retorna o valor do input
            var quantidade = $(this).parent().find('.quantity-col').find('input').val();

            totals += (valor * quantidade);
        });
        $("#totalSoma").text(number_format(totals, '2', ',', '.'));
    }
```

Opcionalmente você pode fazer a busca usando a classe `price-col`. Assim:

```
$(".price-col").each(function () {
            //conteudo da tag td que tem id começando com #preco_
            var valor = $(this).text();
            //encontra a tag tr pai da tag td, depois encontra a tag quantity-col 
            //e retorna o valor do input
            var quantidade = $(this).parent().find('.quantity-col').find('input').val();

            totals += (valor * quantidade);
        });
```

Para mostrar a quantidade total primeiro modifique esse trecho do html:

```
<tbody><tr>
    <td>Quantidade:</td>
    <td id="totalQuantidade">0</td>
</tr>
```

E na função multiplica altere para:

```
var quantidades = 0;
        //procura todos os elementos em que o id começa com preco_ e que está dentro de uma td
        $(".price-col").each(function () {
            //conteudo da tag td que tem id começando com #preco_
            var valor = $(this).text();
            //encontra a tag tr pai da tag td, depois encontra a tag quantity-col 
            //e retorna o valor do input
            var quantidade = $(this).parent().find('.quantity-col').find('input').val();

            if(quantidade != ''){
                quantidades = parseInt(quantidade) + quantidades;
            }
            totals += (valor * quantidade);

        });
        $("#totalSoma").text(number_format(totals, '2', ',', '.'));

        $("#totalQuantidade").html(quantidades);
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%, agora, uma dúvida, se eu quiser contar a quantidade total, como eu faço?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para incluir essa parte.